# How to internationalize form constraints in Play 2.5?

Tags: scala, playframework, internationalization, playframework-2.5

I would like to internationalize the form errors returned by Play 2.5 (Scala), when for example the length of field submitted by the user is 2 and the requirement is 3, I get the following error in Firefox in English: "Minimum length is 3". (The project uses French language and other parts of the site display well in French by using the `conf/messages.fr` file).

```
import play.api.data.Form
import play.api.data.Forms.{ mapping, text }

case class NewsData(title: String, rawHTML: String)

object AllForms {
  val newsForm: Form[NewsData] = Form {
  mapping(
    "title" -> text(minLength = 3, maxLength = 255),
    "rawHTML" -> text(minLength = 3, maxLength = 19999)
  )(NewsData.apply)(NewsData.unapply)
  }
}
```

I have found in the source code of Play that it uses internally the
following message: `error.min` in [Play 2.5 Validation.scala](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.10/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/data/validation/Validation.scala#L102) but putting it in the `conf/messages.fr` doesn't work.

What would be the proper way to localize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong key.

The key [`error.min`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/5428e7f8ed373efd7672eeeb4ea50d80bffcdea0/framework/src/play/src/main/resources/messages.default#L33) corresponds to `Must be greater or equal to {0}`. You should use [`error.minLength`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/5428e7f8ed373efd7672eeeb4ea50d80bffcdea0/framework/src/play/src/main/resources/messages.default#L36) instead, which corresponds to `Minimum length is {0}`.